# Accessing Google Drive Folder within Team Organization using Google Services Account

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api

Using Oauth2 and Google's API I have set up access with a service account, but am struggling to set up access to a specific folder within our team organization.

Currently I am able to do the method calls I want (list, permissions, copy) but the items in the drive that come are only the get started file. I'm not entirely sure which drive this is pulling from as that doesn't exist in any of the accounts I've set the service up in.

My Questions:

- When setting up drive integration using a service account, what is the default drive used and how do I access it via the dev console or gmail account?
- Are you able to access Organization/Team folders and add files to it?

Thank you again for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The drive resource used will be the the Google account which generated the service account in the [Google Dev console](https://pantheon.corp.google.com/iam-admin/serviceaccounts).

> [A service
>   account](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-service-accounts)
>   is a special type of Google account that belongs to your application
>   or a virtual machine (VM), instead of to an individual end user. Your
>   application calls [Google APIs assuming the identity of the service
>   account](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount#overview),
>   so that the users aren't directly involved. A service account can have
>   zero or more pairs of service account keys, which are used to
>   authenticate to Google.

**Are you able to access Organization/Team folders and add files to it?**

If you're application is using a service account to login, yes people you've granted permission can definitely access it and modify the contents depending on the roles you've given them.

You can read more of service accounts in [Using OAuth 2.0 for Server to Server Applications](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount#overview).